# Tool Palette like in MS Paint

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am trying to make a Tool Palette(?) in Qt Designer, like the one like in MS Paint or Adobe Photoshop (on the left side, with various mouse click and selectable tools)

How do i do this? is it using Toolbar?
I need it to be movable within the window

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want you Tool Palette
  floatable then use [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdockwidget.html).
- You may not use toolbar, just use
  simple Tool-Buttons that added to a
  grid-layout Frame (or Widget) Read
  more about [Qt Layout Management](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html)
- And check out Qt examples(included in
  Qt SDK installation) that give you
  many useful clue on Qt programming

Comment: Change your link to http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdockwidget.html.
Chaitu, didn't it solve your problem?